# Use `git add -N` in magit

Tags: magit

Wondering if it's possible to indicate intent to add a file via magit.

The intention would be to stage parts of an untracked file for a commit but leave the rest, rather than the default git add behaviour of adding the entire file (which might have various wip bits).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> on an untracked file invokes the `--intent-to-add` behaviour. You can then stage parts of the file as usual.

(Note though that you cannot *unstage* parts of the file as usual; so be careful of what you're staging.)

Edit: I've just noticed that Magit's ediff<sup>1</sup> integration provides a great workaround for the inability to unstage selected parts in this scenario.

- Type <kbd>e</kbd> on the staged file
- Move to the `.~index~` window, which contains the staged changes
- Edit the content directly (but don't try to save the buffer)
- Exit ediff with <kbd>q</kbd> from the control buffer
- Confirm to Magit that you wish to update the index
- Profit!

---

<sup>1</sup> I'll assume that you already know how to drive ediff.  If not, then (a) I highly recommend taking some time to get familiar with it, because it's great; (b) `ediff-window-setup-function` is the variable to customize to prevent it opening a separate frame for the control buffer; (c) It has its own manual at `C-h i g (ediff)`

Comment: Just dipping my toes into the water with `ediff`, will definitely be digging into it more. Thanks for the tips.