# See untracked file content

Tags: magit

I would like to see the content of the untracked files, so I could see what's there and possibly stage only some lines.

I have `status.showUntrackedFiles = all`, so in magit I can see the files inside a folder that is untracked, but I cant show the content using `TAB` like I can with tracked files.

Answer (score 1):

As each 'diff' would be the entire file, that could be a very costly section to include, even if it were available (which I don't think is the case).

For mere viewing purposes you can, of course, use <kbd>RET</kbd> on an untracked file to visit it.  Maybe not *quite* so convenient in some cases, but it's trivial; you don't have to view the file as a diff; and it has no performance impact on Magit.

For staging purposes, you can use <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to stage an untracked file with `--intent-to-add`, at which point you can stage whichever parts of it you choose.

See also [Use `git add -N` in magit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/37340/454).